# Unable to get the login/register pages with Laravel 8's Jetstream on Apache

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I've installed Laravel version 8, and made a project using the `--jet` flag, I've also run the `npm install && npm run dev` afterwards, and have also run the migrations successfully(confirmed by the artisan's messages and also looking at my database and seeing the tables there), and also the `mydomain.loc` is showing me the Laravel's welcome page, but my problem is that the `mydomain.loc/register` doesn't show the register page, neither does the `mydomain.loc/login`. Entering these addresses in the browser shows the Apache's 404 page(mod_rewrite is enabled too and I've tried restarting the Apache service as well).

I'm running Apache2 on an Ubuntu 20 virtual machine, and it is serving my Laravel's project in the `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproj/public`. Also the MySQL is running in the VM and I've added its info to both the `.env` file and the `config/database.php`, and weirdly everything "seem" to work all fine(Database connection is working... and also the Laravel's welcome page is shown...) except for the login and register pages.

Not sure if it matters, but also since this is only in development, I've done a `chmod 777 -R` on the project's root too, to make sure it's not a permission thing.

Here is my Apache site's configuration(only the parts that matter for this question):

```
# nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.loc.conf
        ServerName mydomain.loc
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.loc

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproj/public
```

And here's what I have inside my `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have your site configured correctly for url rewriting (pretty urls). As you should at the least be getting a Laravel 404 error not the web server. Which means rewriting isn't working and it is looking for a file/folder instead of handing off to the `index.php` file.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Installation - Pretty URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#pretty-urls)

Comment: It makes total sense, and I guessed that might be the case as well, but it's not even mentioned in the manual so I guessed Laravel would handle it itself. Maybe the manual doesn't mention it because they use `php artisan serve` and that probably does these out of the box. Anyway, I'll give it a try now and see if this fixes my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty URLs is mentioned in the documentation and Laravel comes with a `.htaccess` file ... outside of that is your responsibility to know how to configure your server software and understand how it works, they can't go into those details `:)`